# Can I install Ubuntu 16.04 on Macbook 11,1?

Tags: macosx

I am interested of downloading the latest ubuntu on my Macbook 11,1, but according to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro), it only shows Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 14.10 for Macbook 11,1. Does this means it is better if I install the 14.10 version one?

Comment: The link you mentioned is for version-specific wikis. That doesn't mean 16.04 wouldn't run on it. You always can check the compatibility by running live Ubuntu by USB on your machine

Comment: **No, use 14.04LTS.** 14.10 isn't supported anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Found the instructions https://github.com/konklone/ubuntu/blob/master/macbook.md

Please check and report if they help.